# Print stack or row in different ways with same function in Python

Tags: python, queue, stack, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

My task is to print Stack and Queues in different ways.

I implemented Stack with single linked list and Queue with double linked list.

This is main function where I push elements into Stog(Stack) and Red(Queue).

stavi function is same as enqueue, this is in Queue class.

```
def stavi(self, data):

        if self.head == None:
            self.head = Node(data)

        else:
            newnode = Node(data)
            newnode.next  = self.head
            self.head = newnode
```

I cannot change main part!

```
L = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 
S = Stog() 
R = Red() 
for element in L: 
   R.stavi(element)
```

This is how I call function ispis(print):

```
ispis(S)
ispis(R)
```

And this is how I made function ispis:

```
def ispis(self):
 
    
    current = self.head
    if (self.head == None):
        print ("Lista je prazna")
        return

    print("<-- ", end= "")
    while(current != None):
        if (current.next is None):
            print(current.data)
        else:
            print (current.data, end = ", ")
        current = current.next
    return
```

Result should be:

ispis(S) <-- 9 6 14 22 5 5

ispis(R) # 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -->

My results are :

<-- 9, 6, 14, 22, 5, 5

<-- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

I know how to made it for Stack, but how can my code "understand" difference between Stack and Queue. Or should I somehow add elements in Queue from tail ?

Comment: `if isinstance(self, Stog): ...` .`if isinstance(self, Red): ...`

Comment: Yes, sometimes I'm really stupid. Thank you :D

Comment: *"My results are..."*: how is it possible to get output for the stack when you have not populated it? Seems you have not provided the code to reproduce this. Also, you say the Queue is implemented as a doubly linked list, but the `stavi` function (which you say you cannot change) does not even set the `previous` reference... How could this be a doubly linked list??

Comment: "Result should be: ispis(S) <-- 9 6 14 22 5 5": you lost me there. Where do these values come from??

Answer (score 0):

Some issues in the information provided:

- There is no need to implement a queue with a *doubly* linked list. A singly linked list is all you need, but with a reference to both its head and its tail.
- Your code only populates the queue, not the stack
- It makes no sense to expect "9 6 14 22 5 5" as output when the input is "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"
- It is not best practice to have a print method. Printing is a concern that should be kept separate from stack/queue implementation logic. Instead define a method that iterates the values in the list -- for instance by implementing `__iter__`, and if you need a formatted string, `__str__` or `__repr__`.
- If a function is to behave differently for instances of different classes, then it is better practice to define it on each class separately.

Here is an idea of an implementation, where `Queue` inherits from `Stack`. As I don't understand the logic for printing the "#" symbol, I will use "-->" instead, such that an arrow *towards* the list indicates the side where future values will be added, and an arrow *away* from the list indicates the side where values will be removed from the list.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, nxt=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = nxt
    
class Stack:
    def __init__(self, values=None):
        self.head = None
        if values:
            self.insert(*values)

    def insert(self, *values):
        for value in values:
            self.head = Node(value, self.head)

    def extract(self):
        if self.head:
            value = self.head.value
            self.head = self.head.next
            return value

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node.value
            node = node.next

    def join(self):
        return " ".join(map(str, self)) or "(empty)"

    def __str__(self):
        return "<--> " + self.join()

class Queue(Stack):
    def __init__(self, values=None):
        self.tail = None
        super().__init__(values)

    def insert(self, *values):
        if values and not self.tail:
            self.head = self.tail = Node(values[0])
            values = values[1:]
        for value in values:
            self.tail.next = self.tail = Node(value)

    def __str__(self):
        return "<-- " + self.join() + " <--"

values = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
s = Stack(values)
q = Queue(values)

print("Stack", s)
print("Queue", q)
```

As `Queue` inherits from `Stack` the methods to add/remove values are called `insert` and `extract` for both classes. `Queue` overrides the `Stack` implementation of `insert` to change the FILO into FIFO logic.